# multiple row data added to a single row in another table based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am stuck on the following situation and I am wondering how to achieve this.

table1:

```
ID   Data
1     Alpha
1     Beta
1     Gamma
2     Alpha
2     beta
3     Gamma
```

taking the data from table one and showing it like this

Table2:

```
ID   Data
1    Alpha, Beta, Gamma
2    Alpha, beta
3    Gamma
```

Comment: @tim-schmelter: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: could be, feel free to reopen/close it again :)